# Bootstrap 4. HTML CSS and jQuery dropdown submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a HTM code and I am using CSS, jQuery Bootstrap 4 with it. I am trying to create a dropdown submenu upon hover on my main menu. For some reason I am not able to get the dropdown submenu to work. If I hover over my main menu such as Course, TextBook and Car, I want the submenu to display below the main menu. If I remove bootstrap.min.css, the announcement-container div, and custom-menu-container div too, it work without any problem, and If bootstrap and the other menu divs are present, it does not work. And I really need bootstrap and those other menu too. Any help how to get this working please. I am using Bootstrap 4. For the main menu and the submenu, I want the result to look like the image below.[image]

Below is the code

```css
:root {
  --background-color: #FFF;
  --button-bg: #FFF;
  --secondary-bg-color: #F6F5FA;
  --fontfamily: 'Ibarra Real Nova', serif;
  --cormorant: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

* {
  border: none !important;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: var(--background-color);
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

*:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

textarea:focus, input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}


/*-----------------------
/* New Css Added */
/*----------------------- */

.container-fluid.wrapper {
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.logo{
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 0;
  background-size: cover;
}

.announcement-container {
  background: pink;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.announcement-container h5 {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.row.nav-container {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.form-container,
.custome-menu {
  text-align: center;
}

.col-md-6.form-container {
  padding-right: 0px;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.search-product input {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000 !important;
  min-width: 220px;
}

.col-md-6.form-container:hover .search-product input{
  width: 300px;
}

.col-md-6.custome-menu {
  word-spacing: .5rem;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 5px !important;
}

.text-center a {
  color: #000;
}

.col-md-6.custome-menu .fa-a{
  margin-left: .5rem;
}

/*----------------------------
/* Main menu and submenu  */
/*---------------------------- */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-item {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-content {
  background-color: red;
  color: #000;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 60px;
  width: 100% !important;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-content a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-content a {
  display: inline !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  background: red !important;
}

.nav-item:hover a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.navbar-nav li:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.navbar a:hover,
.subnav:hover .subnavbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

.subnav-content a:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: black;
}


.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Lib/fontawesome-5/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="HTest.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper p-0">
      <div class="row announcement-container">
        <div class="col-md-12"><h5>Some text here</h5></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row nav-container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="" class="logo">LOGO
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 custom-menu-container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-container">
              <form class="search-product" action="search" method="get" role="search">
                <input type="text" name="s" id="search_value"
                class="" placeholder="Enter keyword" autocomplete="off" value="">
                <i class="fas fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 custome-menu">
              <a href="#" class="">Create Account</a> /
              <a href="" class="">SignIn</a>
              <a href="" class="fa-a"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
              <a href="" class="fa-a"><i class="fas fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <div class="dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Course<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                  <a href="#">Web design</a>
                  <a href="#">Science</a>
                  <a href="#">Python</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">TextBook</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Car</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>Other text and content will be here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

For the submenu, I want the

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bootstrap `navbar` and then modify the `dropdown` class to get this UI.

```css
.nav-item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-item a {
  color: #FFF !important;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  background: red !important;
}

.nav-item:hover .dropdown-menu,
.nav-item.active .dropdown-menu {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-menu {
  background: red;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: none;
}

.nav-item .dropdown-item {
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  width: auto;
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.dropdown-item:focus,
.dropdown-item:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Lib/fontawesome-5/css/all.css">

<ul class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark p-0 justify-content-start">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link">
          Home
        </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          About
        </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank for the help. It work. This is what i was looking for.